# Ansible with multiple SSH key pair

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible. I am able to test it and its working fine with my test requirment. For making connection between management node and the client node I am using already created ssh key pair. How can I use another node with different SSH key pair? For reference I am considering 3 ec2-instance with different key pairs.

Answer (score 46):

Good news- in a basic use case, this is fairly easy. Simply use the `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` parameter in your [Ansible inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html).

Here are some examples purloined from my personal file:

```
$ cat hosts.ini

[server1]
54.1.2.3 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/server1.pem

[testservers]
ec2-54-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/aws-testserver.pem ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
ec2-54-2-3-5.compute-1.amazonaws.com ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/aws-testserver.pem ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu

[piwall]
10.0.0.88 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/raspberrypi.pem ansible_ssh_user=pi
```

Comment: Thanks tedd its working fine for me. Is it possible to use same key for all the servers of the same group. I mean to say if I have same key for 10 test servers according to above example I have to specify key details for all test server separately.  Any solution is there so that I can pass the same key for all server of same group. Thanks

Comment: @sumitkumar as far as I know, you cannot group the variables in hosts.ini. However, you can use a [ssh_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) file, which may help.

Comment: You certainly can: http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#group-variables

[testservers:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/aws-testserver.pem

Comment: thanks @oley! feel free to edit my answer (or answer it yourself..).

Comment: Does it have to be a `.pem` file? Where do the `.pem` files come from? I see only `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. SSH works, but Ansible won't connect.

Comment: @josh `id_rsa` is your pem. It's just shorthand for "personal key".

Answer (score 29):

tedder42 is correct, however, there is a better way of doing it.

See `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters).

I have in my host files the following

```
# SSH Keys configuration

[all_servers:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file = <YOUR PRIVATE KEY LOCATION>


# Server configuration
[all_servers:children]
elastic_servers
nginx_servers

[elastic_servers]
44.22.11.22
44.55.66.77
22.11.22.33

[nginx_servers]
22.24.123.123
233.111.222.11
```

If you have multiple keys configuration, you can do something like the following

```
[nginx:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file = <YOUR PRIVATE KEY LOCATION>
[app:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file = <YOUR 2nd PRIVATE KEY LOCATION>

[nginx:children]
nginx_servers

[app:children]
app_servers

[nginx_servers]
1.2.3.4
[app_servers]
5.5.5.5
6.6.6.6
```

That's way cleaner than tedder42 answer. This is useful if you have multiple keys for multiple servers.

Otherwise, you can include your key in ansible.cfg file instead.

Comment: If you only have one, you can put it in ansible.cfg as `private_key_file`.

Comment: Currently, I have multiple private keys for the servers I manage.